# Running java classes with ant

Tags: java, ant

I am trying to run my java program using ant. The compile and jar part work perfectly fine. But when u try to run my created Jar, it shows me

> Error: Could not find or load main class com.twu.biblioteca.Application.

Cannot seem to figure out the problem

```
<target name="clean">
    <delete dir="build"/>
</target>

<target name="compile">
    <mkdir dir="build/classes"/>
    <javac srcdir="." destdir="build/classes"/>
</target>

<target name="jar">
    <mkdir dir="build/jar"/>
    <jar destfile="build/jar/Application.jar" basedir="build/classes/com/twu/biblioteca/">
        <manifest>
            <attribute name="Main-Class" value="com.twu.biblioteca.Application"/>
        </manifest>
    </jar>
</target>

<target name="run">
    <java jar="build/jar/Application.jar" fork="true"/>
</target>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your `jar` task. From the [documentation](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/jar.html), `basedir` corresponds to:

> the directory from which to jar the files.

As such, it needs to be

```
<jar destfile="build/jar/Application.jar" basedir="build/classes">
   <!-- ... -->
</jar>
```

With your configuration, you are making a JAR of only the `biblioteca` folder, therefore, it doesn't match anymore the package declaration that contains `com.twu.biblioteca`.

Comment: @Ritabrata Glad I coulp help :). Feel free to [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234) this answer :).